# Graph API: Suggestion of available meeting rooms even though organizer is busy at that given time

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are developing mobile app to book the meeting room based on its availablity at given time using GRAPH API. This is a spcific case where oragnizer is busy in another meeting but he/she still wants to block a meeting room at the same time. FindMeetingTime API is not giving suggestion for rooms if the oragnizer is busy.

[How to display a list of available meeting rooms at present using Microsoft Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46139426/how-to-display-a-list-of-available-meeting-rooms-at-present-using-microsoft-grap)

I have gone through this but this is not going to serve  my problem as I am looking for API which gives meeting rooms suggestions even though organizer is not avaiable.

Can you please suggest any API or any soultion which solves the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create and use any generic service account of  your Active directory that does not belongs to a person and pass it in your Request body as an attendee in your Request to find rooms.it should return room list in response .