# Graph API - Get available room list in the specific time interval

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findmeetingtimes?view=graph-rest-beta

It is showing only the participant's availability. Is there any way to list down the Room's availability in the given time interval?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to list down the Room's availability in the given
>   time interval?

There is no way for now.

But in the MS graph API, you could use [findMeetingTimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findmeetingtimes?view=graph-rest-1.0) to display a list of the available meeting room at present. About the details, you could refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46139426/how-to-display-a-list-of-available-meeting-rooms-at-present-using-microsoft-grap).